# Least squares fit of a symmetric linear system

Tags: matrix, fitting

I have $q$ measurements with $p$ different excitations.

In one special case, they might be equal in length. For example, I might have 12 measurements ($q=12$) with three excitations each ($p = 3$), like so:

```
a0 = {1, 2, 3}
a1 = {0, 4, 1}
a2 = {4, 4, 4}
a3 = {2, 1, 1}
....
a11 = {3, 1, 5}
```

which results in 12 different observations/measurements — in this case also with three elements each (q = 3):

```
b0 = {17, 22, 10}
b1 = {21, 19, 13}
b2 = {40, 48, 20}
b3 = {14, 17, 6}
....
b11 = {22, 34, 11}
```

I would like to know the p x q (in this case 3 x 3) matrix `X`fits best with least squares fit.

$\qquad b_n==X\cdot a_n$ for $n=0\dots11$

Is there's a simple way to get this estimation in Mathematica?

I also have some additional knowledge of the matrix. The elements satisfy

```
X[[i, j]] == X[[j, i]]
```

Is there is a way to make the least square fit aware of the symmetry?

I think this is some sort of multivariate regression, but I don't get the right starting point.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`LeastSquares`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html).

Comment: MarcoB, thank you for the hint. LeastSquare does the job. However - it can not handle the knowledge of equal coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to state this as a minimization problem:

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 11}];
b = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 11}];
xSym = {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3]}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 2], 
    x[2, 3]}, {x[1, 3], x[2, 3], x[3, 3]}};
Minimize[Norm[b - xSym.a, "Frobenius"], Union[Flatten[xSym]]] // N
```

Here a and b are your data matrices, xSym is the symmetric 3 by 3 unknown, and the final line minimizes the norm of b - xSym.a. You could also use other norms:

```
NMinimize[Norm[b - xSym.a, 2], Union[Flatten[xSym]]]
```

or

```
NMinimize[Norm[b - xSym.a, 1], Union[Flatten[xSym]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Works exactly as indented.